# Does the hybrid CPU architecture pose any new issues for VM's, or VM software like VMware, or VirtualBox?

Tags: virtual-machine, cpu

How does Intel's new P/E architecture work with virtual machines? I would imagine software like VirtualBox, and VMWare needed to be worked on & updated to be able to create Virtual Machines using resources allocated from an Alderlake CPU, since there are now 2 core types. Traditionally, when one would allocate cores to a VM using software like virtualbox or VMware, they would provide a single integer, `1 core`, or `2 cores`, or `3 cores`, but with the new Hybrid CPU architecture, it would be an arbitrary statement to say "I want to allocate 5 cores". You would need to explicitly state the type of core you wish to allocate 5 cores of.

IDK how VM's work under the hood , I would imagine that they are a wrapper of sorts, whatever they are, I am sure the new architecture needs to be implimented differently, which requires writing more software, which requires testing, updates, bug fixes etc...

So I was wondering if anyone knows if Alderlake has any issues with running VM's that pre-12th Gen Intel CPU's didn't have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Virtual machine products do not know, and do not need to know, how CPU cores
are allocated.

A virtual CPU is nothing else than a thread spun by the VM product
that executes machine code from and in the context of the VM.
For Windows, this is a thread like
any other, which the Windows scheduler handles normally.

The assignation to P/E cores is done in the operating system, using
data returned by the hardware Intel Thread Director. In fact, this
new technology was one of the main reasons for the architecture of
Windows 11.

I believe that at this time this technology is only used in
Windows 11, but Linux and others may follow in the future.
The Intel CPU will do some assignation of cores on its own,
even when the OS does not support this technology.

More reading :
[How 13th Gen Intel Core Processors Work](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/gaming/resources/how-hybrid-design-works.html).

Comment: It's not that simple, it's asymmetric, the efficiency cores don't support the same instructions, efficiency cores don't have the vector stuff. You make it sound like it can just throw any thread on any cpu, like it doesn't matter. You would be right if the Intel Big/Little wasn't so byzantine.

Comment: @doug65536: I don't say that: "The assignation to P/E cores is done in the operating system", meaning that the virtual machine product doesn't need to know much about the hardware.

Answer (score 2):

We have experienced very poor performance using the new 12 generation Intel architecture with a virtual machine in both Virtual Box and VM-Ware. The virtual machine is running linux with development workloads (IDE, compilation, browser)

We have much better performance from the old 10th generation processors.  It seems that the virtual machine is not ready for this new performance/efficiency architecture.

- Example of 12th gen, with poor VM performance: Intel Core i7-8565U CPU @ 1.80GHz
- Example of 10th gen, with good VM performance: Intel Core i7 10750H CPU @ 2.6GHz

It looks like the VM does need to know about the architecture and be modified to use it well, i.e. ensuring that performance cores are available to the VM workloads.

Comment: See this makes more sense to me, especially from a software developers standpoint. Underneath all the layers of abstraction (the VM is in and of its self a layer of abstraction, created atop severy layers of software-abstraction, there is a low level architecture written for either the VM its self or the languages used to write the VM, and I would imagine that they would need to be optimized, as hardware structure directly impacts theses underlying, low level, logic fate, binary, and assembly written systems.

Comment: i7-8565U is a 8th gen, not a 12th gen. No wonder that 8th gen is worse than 10th gen

Answer (score 0):

My experience has been that Virtual machines are highly hindered by the hybrid cores.

While yes it is the job of the host OS scheduler to organize when and where instructions are set I find that as the layer of abstraction provided by the VM confuses this. I will find frequently that depending on what is running inside the VM that some instruction sets are processed considerably quicker than others.

If you have code that has locks ect and those processes get sent down to the slower cores you can be stuck at a hang. While yes these same problems can exist for the host OS the difference is that the OS scheduler can look ahead and see much further down at the upcoming instructions and better determine where to send the job. When you are using a VM that gets much more abstract and so Yes in order for VM to properly use these new cores effectively much more development is needed. While not an architect here I would imagine the only solution would be that the VMs are going to need to find a way to expose even more of the underlying system to the host.

Honestly I found this post looking to see if anyone had a way to tell the scheduler to only use these cores. The drastic processing speed difference (1.3 v 2.8 ghz) causes massive lag when the wrong actions get placed on the slower cores. Even if I only assign 4 cores (number of performance cores) there is no guarantee what ones will be assigned and I can tell when it's running on the slow ones.